# How do I perform a random from a JSON file in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
{
  "1": {
    "question": "Which one among the following has the largest share of exports from India?\n(a) Agriculture and Allied Commodity\n(b) Gems and Jewellery\n(c) Handicrafts\n(d) Electronic Goods\n",
    "answer": "b",
    "more_info": "India is the leading diamond exporter in the world with an 18.8% market share of an annual export market worth 127 billion dollars.",
    "user_response": "None"
  },
  "2": {
    "question": "What does GST stand for?\n(a) Goods and Sales Tax\n(b) Government Sales Tax\n(c) Goods and Services Tax\n(d) General Sales Tax\n",
    "answer": "c",
    "more_info": "The goods and services tax (GST) is a value-added tax levied on most goods and services sold for domestic consumption. The GST is paid by consumers, but it is remitted to the government by the businesses selling the goods and services. In effect, GST is indirect tax provides revenue for the government. In India it is a comprehensive, multi-stage, destination-based tax that is levied on every value addition.",
    "user_response": "None"
  },
  "3": {
    "question": "In India, GST became active from which date?\n(a) 1st April, 2017\n(b) 1st January, 2017\n(c) 1st July, 2017\n(d) 1st March, 2017\n",
    "answer": "c",
    "more_info": "The Goods and Service Tax Act was passed in the Parliament on 29th March 2017. The Act came into effect on 1st July 2017. It is an Indirect Tax which has replaced many Indirect Taxes in India.",
    "user_response": "None"
  },
  "4": {
    "question": "Indian GST model has a ____ rate structure.\n(a) 3\n(b) 4\n(c) 5\n(d) 6\n",
    "answer": "b",
    "more_info": "In India GST model has 4 basic rate structure. They are 5%, 12%, 18% and 28%",
    "user_response": "None"
  },
  "5": {
    "question": "How many types of taxes are there in Indian GST?\n(a) 2\n(b) 3\n(c) 4\n(d) 5\n",
    "answer": "b",
    "more_info": "There are three types of taxes :\n1. State GST (SGST)/Union Territory GST (UTGST),\n2. Central GST (CGST) and\n3. Integrated GST (IGST) ",
    "user_response": "None"
  }
}
```

I have read about the use of `random.choice` but how do I implement it in my function as presented below:

```
random_questions = random.choices(list(questions.keys()))
    for key, meta in random_questions:
        questions[key]["user_response"] = ask_one_question(meta["question"])
```

I am a beginner working with JSON and Python and any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and clarify your question

Comment: @Tomerikoo, the first code pasted is a JSON file containing an array of data that I'd like to read from. I have, however, been able to read data from it. my question is, how do is how do I randomly read from the data.     `def load_question(filename):
```def load_question(filename):
    """
    loads the questions from the JSON file into a Python dictionary and returns it
    """
    # questions = None
    with open(filename, "r") as read_file:
        questions = json.load(read_file)
    return questions```

Comment: It's impossible to read this. You can [edit] the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you need random.choice() or random.choices(), you refer to both of them in your question, but they are in fact 2 different methods. I assume the latter because of your for loop.

The next problem is that random_questions would be a list of keys, without meta, since you call the .keys() method on it. So perhaps this would work for you:

```
random_questions = random.choices(list(questions.keys()), k = num_of_questions_required)
    for key in random_questions:
        questions[key]["user_response"] = ask_one_question(questions[key]["question"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just attempted reconstructing the code using the above suggestion but I'm getting an error message `not enough values to unpack...`

Comment: how many did you set your k value to? this works for me, using your json dictionary, if I disregard your ask_one_question() function (which I can't see)

Comment: are you sure you've removed the meta from your for loop?

Comment: i did remove it and set the k to 5